# Martingale Difference Sequence

Tags: normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, martingale

I saw that in the [link](http://stat.snu.ac.kr/time/download/%EC%8B%9C%EA%B3%84%EC%97%B4%EB%B6%84%EC%84%9D%ED%8A%B9%EA%B0%9516.pdf) on page 3 it is said $Y_t = e_t\cdot e_{t-1}$ is martingale difference sequence and dependent where $e_t$ is i.i.d with $N(0,\sigma^2)$ Could you provide me with the proof of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, $E[Y_t]=E[e_te_{t-1}]=E[e_t]E[e_{t-1}]=0$; and with some algebraical manipulations we can reach the conclusion $E[Y_t|Y_{t-1},...,Y_1]=0$:
$$\begin{align}E[Y_t|Y_{t-1},...,Y_1]=E[e_te_{t-1}|e_{t-1}e_{t-2},...,e_1e_0]\end{align}$$
Now let $\mathbf{e}_t=[e_t,...,e_0]$, so the given side in the above expectation is a function of $\mathbf{e}_{t-1}$,i.e. a function  $f$ such that $f: \mathbb{R}^{t}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{t-1}$; therefore we need to find $E[e_te_{t-1}|f(\mathbf{e}_{t-1})]$. Using Law of Iterated Expectations, we have
$$E[e_te_{t-1}|f(\mathbf{e}_{t-1})]=E[E[e_te_{t-1}|f(\mathbf{e}_{t-1}),\mathbf{e}_{t-1}]]$$
Since, $f(\mathbf{e}_{t-1})$ is a deterministic function of $\mathbf{e}_{t-1}$, we have
$$E[e_te_{t-1}|f(\mathbf{e}_{t-1}),\mathbf{e}_{t-1}]=E[e_te_{t-1}|\mathbf{e}_{t-1}]$$ which is equal to $E[e_te_{t-1}|e_{t-1},e_{t-2},...,e_0]=e_{t-1}E[e_t|e_{t-1},...,e_0]=e_{t-1}E[e_t]=0$. So, the expected value inside the outer expectation is $0$, i.e. $E[e_te_{t-1}|f(\mathbf{e}_{t-1}),\mathbf{e}_{t-1}]=0$, which means the expectation is $0$, i.e. $E[e_te_{t-1}|f(\mathbf{e}_{t-1})]=0$, which also means the expectation we query in the first place for $Y_t$ is $0$, leading to $Y_t$ being MDS.